# Trying to concatenate a .wav file with another array. Dimensions are giving an error

Tags: matlab

Trying to make the matrix `wave` the same dimension as `t` and `yc`. I would like to concatenate `ww` with `wave` to form `ys`. Don't understand why the .wav file is giving me a `2` in the dimension 2x141363. I need it to be 1x1120001.

[image: image1]

Here is my code

```
[wave,fs] = audioread('myvoice1.wav');
wave=wave';
myCarrierFreq = 560E3;

t=0:(1/(2*560E3)):1;

omega_myCarrier = 2*pi*myCarrierFreq;
modIndex = 0.8;
myCarrierAmp = 4.0;
yc = sin(omega_myCarrier*t);

ww=zeros(1,978638);
ys=horzcat(wave,ww);
```

Comment: You are getting the "2" because the wav file is apparently a stereo signal.  It also only has 141363 samples.  Why do you think that is the wrong number of samples?  What is the value of fs?

Comment: thanks. just figured out how to convert it over to mono (1channel). thanks for the input